# g5 ppc osx 10.5.8 i can't change administrator password

Tags: macos, password, powerpc, administrator

I have a problem with my G5 PPC with OS X 10.5.8. I bought this Mac from an English friend of mine. He forgot an administrator password. I don't have the system CD or Internet connection.

I tried to follow your instructions in other post (command+s) but this is what happens when I do that (on the Mac).

I wrote the command like post and i tried to write in different mode. If you look the last row the command was not found or nothing found to load.

Now i have a new problem. following your instruction this is the results !

i hope you can help me please step by step ... because i'am desperate

Excuse me for my english
[image: problem]

Comment: root is disabled by default on Macs. You'd need to know an admin account & password, other than root. The last owner's name & pass, if they didn't erase all the accounts. Can you post a link to the other question you are referring to, too.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, I see that you've already gotten to "Single User Mode". (Command-S at power on should get you there unless there is an Open Firmware password - in which case you'd need to clear that by changing the installed RAM).

After mounting the filesystem:

```
mount -uw
```

You can change the password of a user:

```
passwd username
```

If you don't know the username, list the user home folders:

```
ls -l /Users/
```